# Symfony 2.5 receive a segmentation fault periodically on errors

Tags: php, apache, symfony

This has been a tough one to troubleshoot. On any error type there was a chance the page would crash with a segmentation fault `[Fri Apr 25 17:45:52.141251 2014] [core:notice] [pid 23298] AH00052: child pid 23367 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`.

I'm running on symfony framework 2.5, with a basic page route and a controller which uses the Request object.

**Route**

```
form_core_page_loader_homepage:
     path:  /
     defaults: { _controller: FormCorePageLoaderBundle:Default:index }
```

**Controller**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// this controller extends Symfony's and adds getStore() function and some others...
use FormCore\PageLoaderBundle\Controller\SessionStoreController as Controller;
use FormCore\PageLoaderBundle\Controller\StyleSessionStoreControllerTrait;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    use StyleSessionStoreControllerTrait;

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


        $store = $this->getStore();

        if (!$store->initRequest($request)) {

            throw $this->createNotFoundException('That page does not exist.');
        }


        // grab our vars for the template...
        $templateVars = $this->getIndexVars();

        ....
    }

    protected functionIndexVars()
    {
        // this is where it goes kaboom
        $noticeErrorHere = $crashesWSegFault;
        ....
    }
}
```

Anyone run into anything at all similar with symfony? My guess is somewhere it's catching errors is causing a problem, very hard to troubleshoot with a seg fault though...

Comment: I suggest you to add xdebug extension to see the correct error, limit the max nesting level to 300, in most cases is a loop recursion.

Comment: That was my thinking too. I added a recurision limit and I haven't seen another seg fault since then, but I'm also not seeing any recursion errors...

Comment: it can be a fastcgi error, try to add 
`IPCCommTimeout 3000
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidIOTimeout 3000`

Comment: There was no delay or timeout issues between the request and seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Symfony 2.5 is being released in the next few weeks, I went back to 2.4 and that seems to have resolved the issue.